# BETWEEN clause breaking with PDO and MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, between

I migrated this over from mysql to PDO.

When I test this query by putting 2 and 19 into the WHERE Clause in place of :id3 and :id4, it works just fine. But when I do it 'correctly' with the :ids, it breaks and I can't spot my error.

Further oddities, it breaks when the range of values i.e. 2-19, crosses 10.

It almost works when I restrict it to between 2 and 6, but, in also includes 21. I am beyond scratching my head at this one.

Will you please put some fresh eyes on this and tell me where it might be wrong?

```
<input name="Between1" id="Between1" type="text" size="5" maxlength="2"  
onKeyPress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) 
return false;"  class="tac" />

<input name="Between2" id="Between2" type="text" size="5" maxlength="2" 
onKeyPress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) 
return false;"  class="tac" />


$stmtAuthorBetween = $con->prepare("SELECT Author, AuthorLN, AuthorNotes 
FROM Authors USE INDEX (XLess) WHERE bookX=:id AND Level=:id2 AND 
(book_NumberX BETWEEN :id3 AND :id4) LIMIT 50"); 
$stmtAuthorBetween->bindParam(':id', $_POST['bookX'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtAuthorBetween->bindParam(':id2', $_POST['Level'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmtAuthorBetween->bindParam(':id3', $_POST['Between1'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtAuthorBetween->bindParam(':id4', $_POST['Between2'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
try {$stmtAuthorBetween->execute();} catch(PDOException $e){ echo 
errorHandle($e);}
$numRowsAuthorBetween = $stmtAuthorBetween->rowCount();
```

The POST array is fine.

I have re-arranged the parentheses every way imaginable.

I changed the bindParam to bindValue.

I removed/replaced the PDO::PARAM_STR with _INT.

I swapped out $_POST['Between1'] and 2 for $one = $_POST['Between1'], then stuck the $one in the bind statement.

I removed the LIMIT and the INDEX.

I tried it with book_NumberX >= :id3 AND book_NumberX <= :id4.

I pulled every extraneous thing out of the original form, nada.

I changed the form to a GET method and the params appeared in the query string perfectly fine, 2 and 6, so the form isn't the issue either.

But in the POST method, it still shows records including 2, 21, 4, 5, 6 when the 21 should not appear.

Why is this query including 21 when it simply wants records BETWEEN 2 and 6?
If I change it to 1 and 6, it includes records 15, 16, etc.

Comment: Is there any error or exception being shown when you try to execute the query?

Comment: Can you show the html of the form you are using to submit please.  I think the problem may lie there

Comment: @Adam Copley - Nope, no error, just no data.

Comment: @AdamCopley - I added the relevant input fields.

Comment: I have deleted my answer for now, as it did not work.  another suggestion would be to in the few lines before you query, `echo $_POST['Between1']`  and check that the form is submitting the correct value, and not something else.  are you sure that the javascript in onkeypress is working corrsectly/

Comment: @AdamCopley - yup, I did that too and it is all showing correctly in the post array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104814/discussion-between-allthisonanacer-and-adam-copley).

Comment: You could try turning on query logging in MySQL to see the difference between using parameter binding and hardwiring the values. Also, does binding with `execute()` i.e. not using `bindParam()` change things at all?

Comment: Hmm, should your numbers be `PDO::PARAM_INT` and not `PDO::PARAM_STR`? (Ah, not this - there's a deleted answer saying the same. I'll leave the comment, as it may be helpful for users who cannot see the deleted answer).

Comment: @halfer - Thanks for your suggestions. I'll look at them in the morning. Your suggestions require me to do some research in how to follow through with them.

Comment: #halfer - I tried the binding to execute() with the same result. It is including records with 20 and 21 in them, rather than just the range between 2 and 6. Can't turn on logging as this is a shared server on which the problem exists.

Comment: @AdamCopley - Just a note to let you know it was in the db varchar instead of int. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @halfer - Just a note to let you know it was in the db varchar instead of int. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed!!

Comment: I too am pleased you got it fixed. However, we do not encourage the wholesale replacement of an original question - please add a self-answer, and tick (accept) it when the system allows you to.

Comment: Okay, I understand, but I replaced the entire question because it no longer reflected the actual nature of the problem. Since someone had responded, I thought I could not delete it. Anyway, I'll answer it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the answer was simple. The data table was years old and the query had worked fine with the table field set to varchar. But when the recordset was upgraded to PDO, I should have changed the table field from varchar to INT. That solved it immediately.

Hope this helps someone else with a similar problem to save some time.